# JS `array.sort` failing in IE6 because its compared values are not numbers. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sorting, internet-explorer-6

I have the following sort function which attempts to sort the items based on whether they start with a value entered into a text box.

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aStart = a.name.match(new RegExp('^' + textEntered, 'i')) || [];
    var bStart = b.name.match(new RegExp('^' + textEntered, 'i')) || [];

    if (aStart.length != bStart.length) {
        return bStart.length - aStart.length;
    }
    else {
        return b.name - a.name; // error because these aren't numbers
    }

    return 0;
});
```

This works in every browser I've tried it in, except for IE6, which returns an error stating that it expected a number.

I tried to implement the suggested fix from this article, which suggests "Don’t reuse the argument variables inside of an Array sort function.": http://www.zachleat.com/web/array-sort with the following:

```
items.sort(function(a1, b1) {

    var a, b;
    a = a1;
    b = b1;

    var aStart = a.name.match(new RegExp('^' + textEntered, 'i')) || [];
    var bStart = b.name.match(new RegExp('^' + textEntered, 'i')) || [];

    if (aStart.length != bStart.length) {
        return bStart.length - aStart.length;
    }
    else {
        return b.name - a.name;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

but it doesn't have any effect. Has anyone had to deal with this before? What's the best fix for this issue?

Comment: doing `new RegExp('^' + textEntered, 'i')` over and over again is horrible for performance. Compute it before you do the sort and reference the variable.

Comment: Thanks for that point @epascarello. I've moved the RedExp object outside the scope of the `sort` call. Considering it's IE6, this is quite important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the comparison between strings and wish to return `-1`, `0` or `1`, use [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```
return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. I edited the answer though because it's actually `localeCompare()`, and not `localCompare()`